# Can I get a Crowbar after I leave Boring Springs?

Tags: west-of-loathing

I've found that I've made a few mistakes in my playthrough so far, one of which is that I didn't get a crowbar when I was in Boring Springs. Is there any way to get one later on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crowbar can appear in one of the shops you'll encounter (the stuff they offer seems to be randomized and I've seen shovels, hammers, picks and other stuff).

This screenshot shows the crowbar appearing at Buttonwillow's store.

[image: buttonwillow shop screen with crowbar for sale]